# What does it mean when the default GitHub page of an NPM module is a fork?

Tags: git, github, npm, module, git-fork

There are many NPM modules for which the main GitHub page is a fork. For example, if I search for `babel-plugin-module-resolver`, the page I get is [github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver).

1. When I download this module with `npm i babel-plugin-module-resolver`, this is the page it pulls it from. What would lead to this fork being the one that's pulled, rather than just `github.com/babel-plugin-module-resolver`?
2. What, if any, other implications are there to the fact that the default location of a module is a fork?

Comment: That's *not* a fork, as far as I can see. What on that GH page makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I thought it was a fork because it has the `tleunen` before `babel-plugin-module-resolver`.

Comment: Forks *say there're forks*, like https://github.com/textbook/postfacto. That's just a regular repo. If it was just github.com/package that would be an account or org.